# Mongoose:Some fields are missing while printing user on console in mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a problem when I am trying to print user on the server console
my code is

```
var user = new User({userid:userid})
    console.log(user)
```

its printing on the console

```
{ userid: 'qq', questions: [], _id: 5ad4602efb255e054412acfa }
```

**but** in my database I have saved user like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad4602efb255e054412acfa"), "id" : 0, "userid" : "qq", "password" : "$2a$10$NNqsVSoTs7eWJiLWy0fZN.0P2mMiiYFYRDFVaLJA9fcY53xRM3uLK", "questions" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

I have five fields in my database 
1-**_id**, 
2-**id**, 
3-**userid**, 
4-**password**, 
5-**questions[]**. But when I am trying to print **user** on the console its not printing some fields...**why?**

my schema is

```
var mongoose = require("../../connection");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({id:Number,
                         userid:String,
                         password:String,
                         questions:[]                           
                        });
var User = mongoose.model("onlineusers",userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

and also when I am trying to print `console.log(user.id)`
its print **undefined**

Comment: Mongoose aliases `id` for `_id`, so that one is explained as a known issue and you simply should not be doing that anyway. `_id` is the **primary key**, so use it. `password` not appearing is another thing, or did you just remove that because your whole question is really about the `id` field?

Comment: yes I am not getting id b'coz somewhere I want to use it....should I change the name of **id** to use it???...